# Override contributed module function

Tags: routes

I'm wondering if it's possible to override a contributed modules hook_menu function.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/ function jquery_ajax_load_menu() {   // Admin settings.   $items['admin/config/development/jquery_ajax_load'] = array(
    'title' => 'JQuery AJAX Load',
    'description' => 'Shows any page on a AJAX link',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('jquery_ajax_load_admin'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),   );   // Only to generate a TAB   $items['admin/config/development/jquery_ajax_load/link'] = array(
    'title' => 'JQuery AJAX Load',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,   );   // Prefix for AJAX requests   $items['jquery_ajax_load/get'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'jquery_ajax_load_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'delivery callback' => 'jquery_ajax_load_delivery_callback',   );   return $items; }
```

Essentially I want to override the **'delivery callback' => 'jquery_ajax_load_delivery_callback',**  So that it calls a modified version of the same function, as apposed to hacking the module.  **'delivery callback' => 'mymodified_jquery_ajax_load_delivery_callback',**

Comment: figured it out, it works correctly (proof is in the pudding?) unless anyone has any comments on how I did it, correct drupal way?

Comment: `<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
 * Remember to clear the menu cache after adding/editing this function.
 */
function jplayer_helper_menu_alter(&$items) {


  // Unset function menu item. 
  unset($items['jquery_ajax_load/get']);
  // Add modified menu item.
  $items['jquery_ajax_load/get'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'jquery_ajax_load_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'delivery callback' => 'modified_jquery_ajax_load_delivery_callback',
  );
  return $items;
}`

Comment: Thw only way to alter the value returned from hooks is to implemente the equivalent alter hook, if there is one used. This is always true.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`hook_menu_alter(&$items)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

```
function yourModule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['jquery_ajax_load/get']['delivery callback'] = 'yourModule_jquery_ajax_load_delivery_callback';
}
```

That's clean and "Drupal way" to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
 */
function jplayer_helper_menu_alter(&$items) {


  // Unset menu item 
  unset($items['jquery_ajax_load/get']);

  // Add modified menu item
  $items['jquery_ajax_load/get'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'jquery_ajax_load_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'delivery callback' => 'modified_jquery_ajax_load_delivery_callback',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to unset all the menu definition to just change the delivery callback.